# Triggering haslayout in IE 6, what's the side effect of using * html div { height: 1%; }

Tags: css, stylesheet, internet-explorer-6

For a while, I've been putting `* html div { zoom: 1; }` in my base stylesheet, and it has worked great. However, I now run into situations where there're elements that are absolute positioned that are losing their heights and widths in IE 6 cuz of this. So I'm thinking of putting `* html div { height: 1%; }` instead, but what are the side effects?

**Update:**

Thanks for all your responses. The answer is most probably no side effects as all of you said.

I will however have to disagree with all your recommendations (at this given moment) about how/when to trigger haslayout. I see haslayout a desirable behaviour and should therefore be a default behaviour in IE6 (& 7).

It's been mentioned that it's unlikely there would be any side effects, for the exact reason, why not make it a default behaviour and only turn it off when an undesirable behaviour (if ever) occurs.

One can do this by specifying `{zoom: auto;}` or `{height:auto;}` on that specific element depending on how it was defined in the base stylesheet.

I will have to give the answer to the first person that said "no side effects" since everyone's answer is the same, while some went out of scope. Thanks again!

Comment: I've always taken the 'do it right then fix IE approach' so applying the hack to everything never really occurred to me. Might be an interesting experiment on my next project, though. See if it kills any IE6 bugs out of the gate. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as [The Holly Hack](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=2&cid=c37E0). As far as I know, there isn't a side effect, especially if you `* html` it for IE6 directly. I agree with the other posters that placing it on the `<div>` tag may not be the wisest choice - I'd target the individual elements that are causing grief.

Answer (score 1):

I try to minimize the use of these kinds of workarounds to avoid unforeseen problems; I only use it on the elements that need it when IE6 breaks a lay-out, never on all elements in a page.

Answer (score 1):

I also don't think there are any side effects.  But as mentioned - only use it on what you need to.  I'd personally...

1. Use it only on a set class:

   - html .haslayout { height: 1%; }
2. Place it in an IE 6 stylesheet included via a [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

   <!--[if IE 6]>
   <link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
   <![endif]-->

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

A 1% height should have no effect because IE treats dimensions as min-dimensions really. However pos:abs is enough to give haslayout anyway and I agree with jeroen that blanket assertions like this are not wise. This is not something you want in a CSS reset for example.